# How to save DICOM image as JPEG without losing information

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dicom

I have a dicom image that when I open it in MATLAB it is like this:

[image]

However when I see that via dicomviewer it is like this:

[image]

How can I save these dicom images without loosing their information in .jpeg format due to compression process?
I want to save the image so that I can retrieve the same information as I get from the respective dicom image.
Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to see the same image on MATLAB, which is currently unavailable (black image)?

Comment: The image you see in Matlab is showing the full range of grey values.  If you adjust the contrast (for example by using imshow(image,[])), then you will see the same as you get with the dicom viewer

Answer (score 11):

DICOM image data is typically stored as 16-bit unsigned integers, so you'll want to make sure that your image is stored within a `uint16` matrix prior to saving so MATLAB knows to save it as such. Also, for some image formats, MATLAB requires that we explicitly state the bit depth.

```
% Save as a 16-bit Baseline JPEG with the highest quality
imwrite(uint16(data), 'image.jpg', 'Quality', 100, 'BitDepth', 16);

% Save as a 16-bit Lossless JPEG
imwrite(uint16(data), 'image.jpg', 'Mode', 'lossless', 'BitDepth', 16)

% Save as a 16-bit JPEG 2000 Image
imwrite(uint16(data), 'image.jp2', 'Mode', 'lossless')
```

If you don't need a JPEG for any particular reason, I would recommend a PNG (lossless).

```
% Save as 16-bit PNG
imwrite(uint16(data), 'image.png')
```

See the full list of available 16-bit formats [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#input_argument_fmt).

For visualization in MATLAB, you can specify the second input to `imshow` (or use `imagesc`) to automatically scale the displayed gray scale values to the data within the image

```
imshow(data, [])    % or imagesc(data); axis image;
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what your 16-bit JPEG is please? JPEGXR? JPEG2000?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have added a link to the documentation which explains a bit more of the details as well as added commands to create both lossless and JPEG2000 images.